# Getting error Expression not in group by value Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have table titanic with columns class(contains 1,2,3 as values ), sex(m,f), survived(0,1). I want to find number of males and females who died in each class.

My code is

```
  select pclass from (
>    select count(survived), sex as s from titanic) t2
> ) group by s;
```

I am getting error 
     FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 2:24 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'sex'

> **Edit:**
>
> I corrected the question with an answer the fix is very small.

Comment: You need to move your group by into the inner select (t2) , since that's where your count is.

Comment: First of all, you should check brackets in your query. You have two open and three close brackets.

Comment: what you are looking here if logically there are many fault aggregation with out group by second pclass is no where in subquerry ...

Comment: I tried by using select count(survived), pclass, sex from titanic
    > where survived = 1
    > group by pclass; I am getting same error